# Use 2 nodes for a single job

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 nodes connected (A, B), and I would like to run a job on A that would simultaneously 'disable' node B during the job run (and run nothing there). I.e. while the job is running on A, no other job can be started on B. And if there is already something running on B, the job on A won't start.

I have looked at the Matrix Project Plugin, but it cannot do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is using the Locks and Latches plugin -  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin.
I created 2 locks, A and B, and the job that needs both nodes requires both of those locks to start. The downside is that all jobs that can ever run on nodes A and B need to configure the plugin correctly (to acquire the A or B lock) for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is but 
[Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) might help you.

This plugin has nothing to do with nodes, but you can block jobs from starting (on any node) while a specific job is running (on any node).

Comment: This would work only partially, I could block the job from starting on A while there are other jobs running on B (I would still need to know the names of all jobs that can be run on B), but new jobs could be started on B during the execution of my job on A, which is a problem.